# How should I run a cron command which has forever loop?

Tags: cron

I have a script that have "while true" loop. And I want to run that script from cron on every minute, so that when the process is killed (or is failed - no matter why) cron will run the script again.

But when I'm checking the `ps -aef --forest` there is my process runned by `/usr/sbin/CROND -n`. This wasn't be bad for cron or system? Or maybe I should do it differently?

Comment: You would be better of to either a) use cron for starting a script that checks for the status of the infinite script and restarts if need be or b) create a systemd service - there you can even define a restart on failure. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310706/can-systemctl-restart-processes-that-have-died-or-is-that-where-supervisor-come). Systemd is a bit hard in the beginning but much more powerful than cron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a short example for a `systemd` service will do.

This is our infinite script, location `/path/to/infinite_script` , executable bit set:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ((1)) ; do
    date >> /tmp/infinite_date
    sleep 2
done
```

No we need to define a service file:

```
[Unit]
#just what it does
Description= infinite date service

[Service]
#not run by root, but by me
User=fiximan
#we assume the full service as active one the script was started
Type=simple
#where to find the executable
ExecStart=/path/to/infinite_script
#what you want: make sure it always is running
Restart=always

[Install]
#which service wants this to run - default.target is just it is loaded by default
WantedBy=default.target
```

and place it in `/etc/systemd/system/infinite_script.service`

Now load and start the service (as root):

```
systemctl enable infinite_script.service
systemctl start infinite_script.service
```

The service is running now and we can check its status

```
systemctl status infinite_script.service

● infinite_script.service - infinite date service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/infinite_script.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-05-28 14:18:52 CEST; 1min 33s ago
 Main PID: 7349 (infinite_script)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/infinite_script.service
           ├─7349 /bin/bash /path/to/infinite_script
           └─7457 sleep 2

Mai 28 14:18:52 <host> systemd[1]: Started infinite date service.
```

Now if you kill the script (`kill 7349` - main PID) and check the status again:

```
● infinite_script.service - infinite date service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/infinite_script.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-05-28 14:22:21 CEST; 12s ago
 Main PID: 7583 (infinite_script)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/infinite_script.service
           ├─7583 /bin/bash /path/to/infinite_script
           └─7606 sleep 2

Mai 28 14:22:21 <host> systemd[1]: Started infinite date service.
```

So note how it was just restarted instantly with a new PID.

And check the file ownership of the output:

```
ls /tmp/infinite/date
-rw-r--r-- 1 fiximan fiximan  300 Mai 28 14:31 infinite_date
```

So the script is run by the correct user as set in the service file.

Of course you can stop and disable the service:

```
systemctl stop infinite_script.service
systemctl disable infinite_script.service
```

---

EDIT:

A few more details: a user's personal services can (by default) be placed in `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/` and managed accordingly with `systemctl --user <commands>`. No root needed just like with a personal crontab.

Answer (score 5):

## mu.

cron is the wrong tool for this job.

The right tool is a *service manager*, one moreover that incorporates the idea of auto-restarting services when they terminate.  (Not all do.)  Such service managers include:

- Dan Bernstein's [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html)
- Adam Sampson's [freedt](http://offog.org/code/freedt/)
- Bruce Guenter's [daemontools-encore](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/)
- Laurent Bercot's [s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/)
- Gerrit Pape's [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/)
- Wayne Marshall's [perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/)
- launchd (MacOS only)
- systemd (Linux only)
- fscd (FreeBSD only)
- supervisord
- My [nosh](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/)

One creates a service definition, appropriate to the service manager, that runs the infinite loop script, and adds it.  For several of the service managers, that's simply a small `run` program (usually itself a script) that execs the infinite loop script.  The service managers do the starting, monitoring, and auto-restarting.

Several of the service managers are easily employed to do per-user service management as well as system-wide, and one can set this up as a per-user service definition of a service that runs as one's own account and can be managed without superuser privileges (which managing system-wide services requires).

## Further reading

- Joshua Timberman (2012-12-29). *[Process Supervision: Solved Problem](http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2012/12/29/process-supervision-solved-problem/)*.
- Larry Doolittle (2005-06-23). *[Unix Daemon Foundations](http://recycle.lbl.gov/~ldoolitt/foundations.html)*.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*The daemontools family*](https://jdebp.uk./FGA/daemontools-family.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- [Ensure a process is always running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/881/5132)
- [How to restart a process automatically when it killed in linux/CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336501/5132)

Comment: Would your point be a little clearer if you disambiguated [`mu`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU) ?

Answer (score 0):

@FelixJN

A caveat: Switching on selinux may prevent your script to run. To get it working, I

1. moved it to `/usr/local/bin` (which is a folder selinux supports)
2. and  edited `/etc/systemd/system/infinite_script.service` to correct `ExecStart` accordingly
3. ran `sudo restorecon -rv /usr/local/bin` to get this information to selinux and
4. ran `systemctl daemon-reload` to finally
5. restart the service `systemctl start infinite_script.service`